# How do I clean bleach marks off bluestone pavers?

Tags: cleaning, pavers, bluestone

I have bluestone tiles in an under cover outside area. I sprayed a household cleaner on sections of the pavers and used a high pressure washer to clean them. However upon drying they now have white bleach spray marks on them where I sprayed.

Is there any way I can get rid of the unsightly "bleach" marks?

Answer (score 2):

The white stains might be dried on soap scum, i.e. calcium etc. salts of detergents. In that case, a vinegar or citric acid solution should solubilize them and allow you to rinse them off with a hose.

Comment: The mild acids you described (used on the balance of the area), might lightly etch the bluestone for a better blend.

Answer (score 1):

Time and sunlight will fade the "clean marks" Stone oxidizes over time and will be self healing.

You might be able to tone it down by carefully using some powered stain 
 used for concrete.